# How to make a function that fills seatings based on surrounding taken/empty seats?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-lists

I have the following nested list, which simulates cinema seating:

Cinema Hall:

```
[
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', '.', 'L', '.', '.', 'L', '.', '.', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', '.', '.', 'L', '.', 'L', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', '.', 'L', 'L', '.', '\n'], 
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '\n']]
```

In this list '.' Stands for no seat, 'L' stands for empty seat, when the function runs '#' should stand for a taken seat.

I have the following function to check the number of surrounding seats in which row stands for column number and seatingstands for row number:

```
numberrows=len(Cinemahall)
seatsperrow=len(Cinemahall[0])-1

def neighbourcounter(cinemahall,row,seating):
    amountseats=0
    for v in range(row-1, row+2):
        for h in range(seating-1, seating+2):
            if v>=0 and v<=numberrows and h>=0 and h<seatsperrow:
                if v!=row or h!=seating:
                    if cinemahall[v][h]=='L':
                        amountseats+=1
    return(amountseats)
```

The following code I want to run multiple times to simulate persons moving positions in a crowded seat, which has three erules:
A seat will get taken if all surrounding seats are empty, and a seat will move from '#' (taken) to 'L' empty if the surrounding seats contain four #
I do this by making and empty list (Cinemahall2)

```
cinemahall2=[]
for eachrow in range(numberrows):
    for eachseat in range(seatsperrow):
        if eachseat == '.':
            Cinemahall2.append('.')
        elif neighbourcounter(Cinemahall,eachrow,eachseat)== 0 and eachseat== 'L':
            #if eachseat== 'L':
                Cinemahall2.append('#') 
        elif neighbourcounter(Cinemahall,eachrow,eachseat)>= 4 and eachseat== '#':
            #if eachseat== '#':
                Cinemahall2.append('L')
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-62e4580e39c2> in <module>
      8             Cinemahall2.append('.')
---> 9         elif neighbourcounter(Cinemahall,eachrow,eachseat)== 0 and eachseat== 'L':
     11             #if eachseat== 'L':
     12                 Cinemahall2.append('#')

<ipython-input-4-c270a8cd4d30> in neighbourcounter(Cinemahall, row, seating)
     13             if v>=0 and v<=numberrows and h>=0 and h<seatsperrow:
     14                 if v!=row or h!=seating:
---> 15                     if cinemahall[v][h]=='L':
     16                         amountseats+=1
     17     return(amountseats)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, wasn't aware, fixed it

Comment: That's a big improvement, but you need to also provide a runnable [mre]. It would also be helpful if you removed all the commented-out code and corrected the indentation. Besides that, generally speaking I think it would make your code more readable if you replaced the character literals with symbolic names. e.g. `NONE = '.'`, `EMPTY = 'L'`, `TAKEN = '#'`.